# AngularJS directive input fields are read only

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I am trying to write an AngularJS (version 1.4.8) directive which outputs the value of an attribute in an input box. The directive looks like this:

```
(function () {

    angular.module("myApp").directive("inputAttributeDirective", function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "inputAttributeTemplate.html",
            // The directive is a custom element
            restrict: "E",
            // Declare the scope of the directive as isolated
            scope: {
                attribute: "=",
                value: "="
            }
        }
    });

})();
```

And the HTML template for it is the following (that's in inputAttributeTemplate.html):

```
<label id="AttributeLabel" class="control-label">{{ attribute }}</label>
<div id="AttributeInput" class="input-prepend">
    <input id="attributeName" name="attributeName" class="form-control input-large" type="text" ng-model="value"/>
</div>
```

Where 'attribute' and 'value' correspond to the attributes of an object called 'Client' that looks like this:

> vm.client = {
>               name: "Some Client",
>               description: "This is a cool client",
>               networkPath: "network path 1",
>               active: "1"
>           }

So basically, a Client has four attributes, **name**, **description**, **networkPath**, and **active**.

And the way I am including the directive is like so (this is in the parent HTML file):

```
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.client">
            <incident-attribute-directive attribute="key" value="value"></incident-attribute-directive>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The problem is that, while it does display the attributes correctly, they are read-only and I need them to be editable:

[image]

Any idea why they are read-only?

Comment: Are the inputs in a fieldset tag? If so the fieldset may be set to readonly

Comment: Can you post a plunkr?

Comment: @UmerZ Nope, not in a fieldset

Comment: Also, probably a typo, but your directive's don't match. Just making sure you are using the correct directive. `incident-attribute-directive`vs `inputAttributeDirective `

Comment: @Ronnie That was it! Wow I can't believe I missed that. I feel silly now. Thanks.

Comment: happens to all of us lol

Comment: I think the problem is not here... It may come from css, inspect elements to see this.

Comment: @sylvain1264 The problem has been fixed. It was caused by me mistyping the name of the directive, as Ronnie pointed out.